I'm having trouble centering the logo in this PyQt window
I have divided my central QWidget into two sides: Left and Right. The left side contains the logo, and the right side widget contains the sign-in box.
Because I want the sign-in box to be a fixed size and a certain distance from the right-side margin, I've included a QSpacerItem to achieve the desired behavior.
However, after adding the QSpacer to the right frame, my logo gets pushed off-center. To counterbalance that, I added a QSpacer to the left-side frame too.
When I run the code, everything works as expected, but when I expand the screen, the logo gets pushed to the right. I've added a second QSpacer to the right of the logo to sandwich it in, but I still can't get the logo centered.
When the spacer is only added to the right_side_frame:

GUI after sandwiching the logo between two spacers:

What I'm trying to recreate:

the logo doesn't look centered in the full window because of the space within the right frame
#Login Window
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from ColorWidget import Color

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # Window Properties
        self.setWindowTitle('login window')
        self.setMinimumSize(1050, 650)

    #Main Layouts
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        left_side_frame = QWidget()
        right_side_frame = QWidget()


        main_layout.addWidget(left_side_frame)
        main_layout.addWidget(right_side_frame)

        
    #Left Layout
        left_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        left_h_spacer = QSpacerItem(200, 20, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
        left_layout.addItem(left_h_spacer)

        #label
        logo_label = QLabel('logo')
        logo_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        left_layout.addWidget(logo_label)

        left_side_frame.setLayout(left_layout)

        right_side_spacer = QSpacerItem(200, 20, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
        left_layout.addItem(right_side_spacer)


    #Right Layout

        right_layout = QHBoxLayout()


        #Sign-in Box
        signin_box = Color('white')
        signin_box.setObjectName('signin_box')
        signin_box.setFixedSize(450,550)

        Spacer = QSpacerItem(200, 20, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        right_layout.addItem(Spacer)
        right_layout.addWidget(signin_box)

        right_side_frame.setLayout(right_layout)
        right_side_frame.setContentsMargins(0, 50, 80, 50)

    
        # Set main widget
        canvas = QWidget()
        canvas.setObjectName('canvas')
        canvas.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(canvas)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    with open('style.css', 'r') as f:
        app.setStyleSheet(f.read())
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()


stylesheet:
#canvas {
    background-image: url('Images/test2.jpg');
    background-position: center;
}

#sign_in_label {
    color: black;
    font-size:  24px;
}
#email_label, #password_label, #register_label {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
}

I somewhat get the logo centered by using this values:
left_h_spacer = QSpacerItem(500, 20, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
        left_layout.addItem(left_h_spacer)

right_side_spacer = QSpacerItem(300, 20, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
        left_layout.addItem(right_side_spacer)

my screen size is 1512, 982

Please provide a couple of images showing what you get and what you actually want. Also, the style sheet may be relevant, so you should include it too (possibly removing everything that is not relevant to the issue).

Sorry but it's still unclear what the expected result should be, especially considering that your "logo" is just a text right now. As said, please provide images of what you actually want, possibly showing the differences when the window is eventually resized.

Got it. I've added an image of what I'm trying to replicate. Adobe, sign in page.  In the example provided, adobe photoshop is centered between the left screen margin and the white sign-in box.

You should make more clear what the actual proportions should be, as you're using a basic text label (which is also extremely small), and the latest image you've provided does not have the logo centered to any visible reference. So, it's important to know: 1. to what the logo should be actually centered (eg: the available space between the left edge of the window and the left edge of the form); 2. the possible minimum margins between the window edges; 3. how those margins should change when the window is resized; 4. how the proportion should eventually change for the logo position.

It will certainly help (not only us, but you too) to draw a sketch that shows the individual vertical sections, also displaying which ones should be fixed, or might be expanded, or even stretched (and to what extent), and the possible ratios that are expected from expanding/resizable sections. I also suggest you to take some time and play around with Designer, by changing layout stretches and size policies of items. Having a visual clue of the desired result always help to understand how the final layout structure should be done.

I see my mistake. The "logo" is indeed centered within its container. However, because the left and right frame are not visible, it looks like the logo is not centered because of the background image. Added an Image for Illustrations. I've fixed this by adding a stretch factor of 1 to the left frame @musicamante.

I was able to solve the problem. I was able to keep the logo centered by adding a stretch factor of 1 to the left_side_frame:
#Login Window
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from ColorWidget import Color

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # Window Properties
        self.setWindowTitle('window title')
        self.setMinimumSize(1050, 650)


    #Main Layouts
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        left_side_frame = QWidget()
        right_side_frame = QWidget()

        main_layout.addWidget(left_side_frame,1)
        main_layout.addWidget(right_side_frame)

        
    #Left Layout
        left_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        #label
        logo_label = QLabel('logo')
        logo_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        left_layout.addWidget(logo_label)

        left_side_frame.setLayout(left_layout)


    #Right Layout

       #widgets and code for the right Layout

    # Set main widget
        canvas = QWidget()
        canvas.setObjectName('canvas')
        canvas.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(canvas)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    with open('style.css', 'r') as f:
        app.setStyleSheet(f.read())
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

